# DAX string that returns all the values in the filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way to pass a string to the FILTER condition which would mean a release of all filters applied?

```
VAR MyFilter = IF( condition, "red", "%%" )
CALCULATE ( [Sales], tab[color] = MyFilter )
```

I am asking about "%%". Is there any way to have a conditional filter that returns either the "red" color or all color values?

Edit. Sample data

```
DATATABLE (
    "Color", STRING,
    "Sales", INTEGER,
    {
        { "red", "1" },
        { "blue", "1" },
        { "yellow", "1" }
    }
)
```

Comment: Filters are tables so yes this is possible but hard to advise further without test data and expected output.

Comment: @DavideBacci nothing more simpler, there you are. The string should return all three colors in a similar way as SQL where Color like "%e%" would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workaround. As an example condition, I check if the color contains the letter "L". Of course, it could be whatever condition. The Measure mimics the behavior of the impossible:

```
CALCULATE( [Sales], IF( Condition, Result_1, Result_2) )
```

where Result_1 and Result_2 are filters that modify CALCULATE.

```
Measure = 
var MyCondition = CONTAINSSTRING( SELECTEDVALUE(Tab[Color]), "l" ) // whatever condition
var Result_1 = ALL( Tab[Color] )
var Result_2 = TREATAS( {"red"}, Tab[Color] )
var MyFilters =
UNION( 
    FILTER( Result_1,     MyCondition ),
    FILTER( Result_2, not MyCondition ) // mutually exclusive condition
)
return
    CALCULATE( SUM( Tab[Sales] ), MyFilters )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can’t test this, but thinking `TREATAS` might be a solution here. Wrap `red` in curly braces to make it into a table, and supply a table of all other colors if the condition predicate is false.

```
Sales =
VAR MyFilter = IF ( condition, {"red"}, ALL ( tab[Color] ) )
RETURN
CALCULATE ( [Sales], TREATAS ( MyFilter, tab[Color] ) )
```

Comment: No, it won't do it. IF returns scalar. But actually, you have inspired me to crack it. I'll post a solution.